# Одинаковая высота для button и select в firefox (без heigh)

Tags: html, css

Не могу установить одинаковую высоту для button и select в firefox.
Убрал все отступы, а размеры стабильно отличаются на 2 px. Подскажите в чём проблема. Указывать строгий height или использовать flex для выравнивания не хочу.

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/7emhcn5r/

```
<button>X</button>
<select name="" id="">
  <option value="">X</option>
  <option value="">X</option>
</select>
```

## UPD

В хроме при `-webkit-appearance: none;` блоки становятся одинаковой высоты. В firefox (с префиксом `-moz-`) это не помогает.

Есть ли способ это исправить?

Comment: На кнопку влияет line-height, а на select нет. В вашем примере высота выровняется если поставить его 19px. Но я бы так не заморачивался и использовал flex контейнер или высоту в rem.

Comment: @Talleyran это неправильный вывод. Проблема в свойстве `appearance`. В хроме при `-webkit-appearance: none;` блоки становятся одинаковой высоты. В firefox это не помогает